# My Program Is Being Slow On CellFormating Event How Fix That?

Tags: c#, loops, datagridview, cell-formatting

I Have A Function In My CellFormating Event And That Function Have Two For Loop To Check That In A Row Exist A NULL Cell Or Not And Then Change The Row Header Of DataGridView

But My Program is Slow Down And I Cant Do Any Thing Any More How Can I Fix That ??

```
    private void dgv_tests_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
            {
                RowHaveNull();
            }
```

```
 private void RowHaveNull()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dgv_tests.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dgv_tests.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    dgv_tests.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = MyGreen;

                    if (dgv_tests.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == null || dgv_tests.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() == "")
                    {
                        dgv_tests.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = MyYellow;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Note the this event occurs for each Cell, so your loops may be quite unnecessary. You can get the row&column from the event parameters and pass them into any function you need..

Comment: @TaW Because I Want That If Any Nulls Found On Row Make A Yellow RowHeader I think That Need This loops Am I wrong ?

Comment: It is unclear what the method `RowStyler(e)` is doing and I can only guess it may fall into the same category as the `RowHaveNull()` method…but... It looks like you may be using the wrong event for what you are wanting to do. The grids `CellFormatting` event will fire even if the user simply moves the cursor over a cell. So basically, the code is re-setting (the same) row header cell’s color needlessly over and over… when NO value in the grid changed. You want to use an event for when a cell value “changes” like the `CellValueChanged` event.

Comment: @JohnG Thats Correct answer And I use Wrong Event Thank u so much

Comment: It would be the *wrong event* in any case if you loop the entire grid. In `CellFormatting` or `CellValueChanged`, the prefix - *Cell* -  gives it away: you handle a single Cell and provide formatting for that Cell alone -- There are rare cases when you actually need to loop the Rows of a DGV (often just because of a design choice - or lack thereof); never in normal conditions.